# Using CASE to select a field in SQL?

Tags: sql

Based on if one field in the database is equal to something, I want to select the value of another field. I was thinking that I could use `CASE THEN` but I can't get it to return the value of a field.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT LastName, CASE FirstName WHEN 'Ian' THEN JobNo END FROM Employees
```

`JobNo` is the name of the field which I want to get the value from.

Comment: You haven't shown the definition of your table(s), without which it's hard to give a good answer.  See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you're missing the else statement in your case statement, once that's in there it should work

like this:

```
SELECT LastName, 
    CASE FirstName WHEN 'Ian' THEN JobNo ELSE -1 END
FROM Employees
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
SELECT LastName, CASE  WHEN FirstName ='Ian' THEN JobNo else null END
FROM Employees
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the ELSE:

```
SELECT LastName, CASE FirstName WHEN 'Ian' THEN JobNo ELSE FirstName END
FROM Employees
```

I've defaulted to return the FirstName, if you don't want that just replace with something else. Just make sure the datatypes are equivalent to avoid potential issues (I've assumed JobNo is a varchar ref code for purpose of demonstrating syntax).

Comment: *cough* type mismatch *cough*

Answer (score 1):

Adding an ELSE condition won't hurt, but you may also need a column name for your new column - like so:

```
SELECT LastName, 
       CASE FirstName 
            WHEN 'Ian' THEN JobNo 
            ELSE 0
       END  IansJobNo
FROM Employees
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
SELECT LastName, 
    JobNo = CASE 
        WHEN FirstName = 'Ian' THEN JobNo END
FROM Employees
```

Answer (score 0):

The sql syntax seems correct to me.  I tried it myself and works fine.  May be you are missing something else.  The following is a sample output I get,
[image]

Answer (score -1):

CASE @Temp WHEN 1 THEN ISnull(tbl1.t1,0) WHEN 2 THEN ISnull(tbl1.t2,0)  END AS Value

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.