# Concatenate CASE WHEN results in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation, case

I have a table in an MSSQL database that is structured like this. I have read-only rights on this table and it contains more than 10 million rows in this structure:

| patient_number | form | text | answer | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | 'q1' | '-' | '-' |
| 1 | A1 | 'q2' | '-' | '-' |
| 1 | A1 | 'date' | 10-10-2010 | '-' |
| 1 | A1 | 'disease A' | '-' | 'Yes' |
| 1 | A1 | 'disease B' | '-' | 'Yes' |
| 2 | A1 | 'q1' | '-' | '-' |
| 2 | A1 | 'date' | 20-10-2010 | '-' |

Now, I wish to extract data via a select statement so the output will be:

| patient_number | form | date | disease A | disease B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 | 10-10-2010 | 'Yes' | 'Yes' |
| 2 | A1 | 20-10-2010 |  |  |

What I tried so far, using a CASE WHEN statement:

```
SELECT patient_number, form,
(CASE WHEN text = 'date' THEN answer ELSE NULL END) AS date,
(CASE WHEN text = 'disease A' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS disease A
FROM dbo.view_oog
```

Unfortunately, this SQL statement also includes all NULL rows and is typically slow. I am looking for some advice to solve this problem. Looking forward to learn from you.

Some posts I looked at:

[Using CASE to select a field in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142486/using-case-to-select-a-field-in-sql)

[Selecting only rows that return a matching column value using CASE THEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26868887/selecting-only-rows-that-return-a-matching-column-value-using-case-then)

Comment: "SQL statement also includes all NULL rows"  What about adding a WHERE clause ?

Comment: About performance, please add the RDBMS you are using.  There is a slight difference in solving performance issues. In general you need a correct index.

Comment: Thanks Luuk, RDBMS added.

Answer (score 1):

Try using both MAX and GROUPBY:

Example below:
Let me know if it works

```
SELECT 
    patient_number, 
    form, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN text = 'date' THEN answer ELSE NULL END) AS date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN text = 'disease A' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS disease_A,
    MAX(CASE WHEN text = 'disease B' THEN value ELSE NULL END) AS disease_B
FROM 
    dbo.view_oog
GROUP BY 
    patient_number, 
    form
```

Comment: I really appreciate it, thanks. I left you an upvote :)